# Why is this matrix computation always positive semi-definite

Tags: matrices

The objective is to prove that $C$ is positive definite. I already know that $Q$ is positive def, and i also know that $P$ is positive def and symmetric.

$-Q -A^TPB \lambda B^TPA = -C \quad where \;, Q,P \succ 0, \; B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}, \; A,P,Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n},\; \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{1}$

The objective is hence to prove that the equation below holds (meaning that it's positive-semi definite). I've ran some test in matlab and it seems to hold when i randomize $A, B, P$ with the properties stated above. But i cannot seem to grip my head around why.

$A^TPB B^TPA \succeq 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A^TPB B^TPA$ is positive semidefinite because $x^TA^TPB B^TPAx=(B^TPAx)^T(B^TPAx)=\|B^TPAx\|^2\ge0$ for every vector $x$.

In general, if $M$ is a real (resp. complex) matrix, $M^TM$ (resp. $M^\ast M$) is always positive semidefinite for the same reason. The product $M^TM$ (or $M^\ast M$) is known as the [*Gram matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) of $M$ with respect to the usual inner product.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense :)